# Graph classification

Tags: python, machine-learning, graph

I do graph classification, read an edgelist file, split to train and test and check if the train set is a connected graph by using networkx:

```
import networkx as nx
trainGraph = nx.read_edgelist('trainEdgelist.txt', create_using=nx.Graph(), nodetype=int)
nx.is_connected(trainGraph)
```

If I want to use 10-fold cross validation and use something like:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
KFold(n_splits=10, random_state=None, shuffle=False)
```

how can assure that every fold's train set is a connected graph?

How can I add such a condition?

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: do k-fold cross validation by splitting the data in such a way that the train set of every fold is a connected graph.

Comment: k-fold comes from conventional data where you can split the data-set to smaller independent records, you cannot do this with graph for the obvious reason it can't be split so it will keep it's properties, maybe you can mimic the k-fold operation, but I'll need to know what is your use case...

Comment: @shahaf thank you for your answer. Before creating the graph, the data is saved in edgelists, like .txt files. I realized that when there is also time dimension (as in my case), classic k-fold cannot be performed. In this case I can implement forward k-fold, like:
- fold 1 : training [1], test [2],
- fold 2 : training [1 2], test [3],
- fold 3 : training [1 2 3], test [4],
- fold 4 : training [1 2 3 4], test [5],
- fold 5 : training [1 2 3 4 5], test [6]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still don't fully understand your goal, will try to answer as best as I can

basically [KFold](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.KFold.html)` return segmentation of the data-set by it's indices, and it's input is an array-like object, this is a "stupid" function which just split an array with no farther logic...

you'll need to create the data-set with the following structure:

> array-like object where each item is a connected graph (and another array for it's label `y` if this aplicable in your case)

once you have this object you can use `KFold()` in order to create multiple tests and train sets

in order to create a bunch of connected graph you can choose a variety of methods like:

- remove X random edges and check if the graph is connected (do this N times)
- add edges and nodes by an increment manner as you stated in your comment, adding edges by an order and check if the graph is connected with every addition

*the problem with those is they are both time consuming and might not converge, highly depends on their input (random state and order of edges)*

My suggestion is to find the **MST** of the graph, this is the base connected graph, to create variations of it just randomly add any edge/s which is/are not part of the MST